# Has Anyone Gotten Hibernate to Use Elasticache as its 2nd Level Cache?

Tags: java, hibernate, amazon-ec2, amazon-elasticache

I found some threads saying this was doable, but did not find specific instructions or config information.

I want to do this from Beanstalk as well: the app should get deployed to beanstalk with a config that points hibernate to the elasticache instance(s).

Comment: I managed to connect to ElastiCache with memcache implementation, but describing it will take me a while. But I haven't tried that from Beanstalk...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, we were able to configure hibernate with 2nd level cache.. Not with beanstalk though.. This code should help you with it.

```
<props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">false</prop>


            <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_structured_entries">true</prop>
            <!-- prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" >update</prop -->
            <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">100</prop>


            <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">com.googlecode.hibernate.memcached.MemcachedCacheProvider
            </prop>
            <!-- Cache disabled -->
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.memcached.servers"><elasticachehostname>:11211</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.memcached.cacheTimeSeconds">300</prop>



            <prop key="hibernate.memcached.connectionFactory">DefaultConnectionFactory</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.memcached.clearSupported">false</prop>


        </props>
```

You would need the [hibernate memcached](http://code.google.com/p/hibernate-memcached/wiki/Configuration) jar as well

Comment: Don't you also have to add `@Cache` and `@Cachable` annotations for the Hibernate entities that you'd like to cache?