# How to configure Amazon Elasticache with Hibernate second level cache (Hibernate 5.0.7 & Wildfly 10.0.0)

Tags: java, hibernate, second-level-cache, amazon-elasticache, wildfly-10

I want to configure Hibernate's second level cache to use AWS Elasticache (currently trying to use memcached). I've looked at things like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8765913/has-anyone-gotten-hibernate-to-use-elasticache-as-its-2nd-level-cache), but can't seem to get it to work.

In the Hibernate 5.0 docs, it says that Wildfly automatically configures Hibernate's second level cache to use Inifinispan. Is there an easy way to disable this? Does configuring the cache to use elasticache (correctly) override this?

How can I configure the cache to use memcached in Hibernate 5? Several places say to set the property "hibernate.cache.provider_class" but the Hibernate 5.0 docs say that the property "hibernate.cache.region.factory_class" needs to be set to determine which provider to use. Also are old versions of hibernate-memcached (like [this](https://github.com/raykrueger/hibernate-memcached)) still usable?

Comment: What's the reason why you want to avoid using default Infinispan 2LC provider in Wildfly? :)

Comment: We have multiple servers that we want to access the same cache so we don't get stale data -- hence the use for elasticache

Comment: If those servers deploy the same version of the code, specially when it comes to the Hibernate/JPA classes, you could cluster those servers and take advantage of Infinispan-based distributed 2LC...